# Dynamically call function name in python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to call function name dynamically if present in the list of dictionary, if present call the function else exit silently. How can I achieve this, tried below locals approach but didn't works

```
jobs = [{
        "job": "IT",
        "company": "google"
    },
    {
        "job": "Sales",
        "company": "walmart"
    }
]

def IT(name):
    print('Full %s' %name )

def Sales(name):
    print('View %s' %name)

name = 'department'
Input_Job = 'Sales'
locals()[jobs['job'][Input_Job]](name)
```

expecting output is Input_Job = 'Sales'

```
View department
```

expecting output is Input_Job = 'IT'

```
Full department
```

Comment: What do you expect the output for your example to be?

Comment: I think there are more problems with your last line - can you clarify your intentions for it? Also - hint - try: `locals()[jobs[1]['job']](name)
`

Comment: Tried per your note `locals()[jobs[1][Input_Job]](name)` but it errored ```KeyError: 'Sales'```

Comment: Add the function objects to the dictionary and this should just work.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga how function object can be added to the dictionary. jobs list is a json file that i'm trying to consume